# How Can I Change The Color of Active Navbar Item?

Tags: css, text, colors, menu, navbar

My theme colors are black, white, and #039258

I want the active navbar item to be #039258, but it's currently #0bb4aa

Code:

```
.current_page_item {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #039258;
}
```

```
.navbar-nav li>a:hover,.navbar-nav li>a:focus,.navbar-nav li.active {
        background-color: #039258;
    }
```

Comment: please include the code

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I'm still learning and appreciate your patience :)
I've updated my original question with some CSS code. There is a lot of code so please let me know if this is the info you need!

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? If so, what version?

Comment: I've seen that term but am not sure what it is... my website is built on Wordpress using CSS and I'm attempting to make the adjustment via Custom CSS

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I needed to add "> a" after current_page_item. I also used !important to make sure it doesn't get overridden by the theme's native font color.

```
.current_page_item > a{
  color: #039258 !important
}
```

Comment: The answer is good in format and content.
If anything, I would recommend you wrap snippets of code within the line in ` characters. For this case, you could write the following:
I needed to add `> a`after the `current_page_item` element. I also used `!important` to make sure it doesn't get overridden by the theme's native font color.